# How to remove all observations before this one in Stata?

Tags: stata

Using Stata, I would like to drop all observations that come prior to the current one if a certain criterion is met.

To be exact, in this sample I would like to drop all observations that appear before an observation with a `close` of `0`.

```
t   close   id  rdate
MPC 0       MPC 31may2011
MPC 0       MPC 01jun2011
MPC 0       MPC 24jun2011
MPC 37.65   MPC 27jun2011
MPC 38.7    MPC 28jun2011
MPC 40.07   MPC 29jun2011
MPC 0       MPC 30jun2011
MPC 42.2    MPC 01jul2011
MPC 42.21   MPC 05jul2011
MPC 41.89   MPC 06jul2011
MPC 41.78   MPC 07jul2011
MPC 41.41   MPC 08jul2011
MPC 40.1    MPC 11jul2011
MPC 40.48   MPC 12jul2011
MPC 39.96   MPC 13jul2011
MPC 38.64   MPC 14jul2011
MPC 39.16   MPC 15jul2011
MPC 39.12   MPC 18jul2011
MPC 39.74   MPC 19jul2011
MPC 39.53   MPC 20jul2011
MPC 40.1    MPC 21jul2011
MPC 40.57   MPC 22jul2011
MPC 41.37   MPC 25jul2011
MPC 43.05   MPC 26jul2011
```

Something like: `by t: drop if _n* < _n & close == 0` would then have to result in:

```
t   close   id  rdate
MPC 42.2    MPC 01jul2011
MPC 42.21   MPC 05jul2011
MPC 41.89   MPC 06jul2011
MPC 41.78   MPC 07jul2011
MPC 41.41   MPC 08jul2011
MPC 40.1    MPC 11jul2011
MPC 40.48   MPC 12jul2011
MPC 39.96   MPC 13jul2011
MPC 38.64   MPC 14jul2011
MPC 39.16   MPC 15jul2011
MPC 39.12   MPC 18jul2011
MPC 39.74   MPC 19jul2011
MPC 39.53   MPC 20jul2011
MPC 40.1    MPC 21jul2011
MPC 40.57   MPC 22jul2011
MPC 41.37   MPC 25jul2011
MPC 43.05   MPC 26jul2011
```

This seems trivial but I just cannot figure it out.

The main problem is that I  do not know how to describe or name this technique, and therefore I cannot search for it.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be compressed. The last zero is at

```
egen lastz = max(rdate / (close == 0)), by(id)
```

Then you can

```
drop if date < lastz
```

You can Google for my article "Compared with..." In the *Stata Journal* for discussion of this technique. You will get missings automatically if there are no zeros.

Comment: Hmm, you are dividing by zero when `close != 0`?

Comment: Exactly; and deliberately so. Dividing by zero produces missings, but they will be ignored unless all values for a panel are missing. Either way, it should be fine.

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore in Stata 13. Something changed?

Comment: Nothing has changed that would undo that trick. "does not seem to work anymore" is no detail at all; we need reproducible examples to comment  on apparent problems.

Answer (score 0):

I now managed to find a workaround for this problem, using the following "hack". However, I would appreciate a faster and cleaner way to do this.

```
* drop all obs before a close price of 0 if occuring *
sort ticker_id rdate
gen tagdate = rdate if close == 0
by ticker_id: egen lasttagdate = max(tagdate)
drop if rdate <= lasttagdate & !missing(lasttagdate)
drop tagdate lasttagdate
```